# Build binding from proterty value

Tags: angular

I would like to use a property for data binding myself.
Here is an example. I have a list of items:

```
[{name='name1', invalid='error.name1'}]
```

And another list of errors.

```
errors : any= ['name1': 'Here is an error']
```

If I now use the data binding, the following becomes from it

```
<div class="input-group-addon addon-valid"
     [class.addon-invalid]="item.invalid"
```

But actually, that would have to be  interpeated like

```
<div class="input-group-addon addon-valid"
     [class.addon-invalid]="errors.name1"
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work if the values (`item.invalid`) don't contain a `.`:

```
 [class.addon-invalid]="this[item.invalid]"
```

If it contains a `dot you'd need some helper method, but binding to methods needs to be carefully done to not cause huge performance issues.

Comment: Ok. I understand. Do you have a example for a function?

Comment: No. You need to split the string at `.` and iterate the object tree using `obj[propName]` syntax. There might be JavaScript examples. This isn't Angular specific, only the part of using it in view bindings is Angular specific.